# flutter how to get code line numbers 'Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite, flutter-moor

I am using moor and sqflite and added different database helpers.
 Now my problem is how to identify which line is making this error? 
 Is there any way to get the error line

Comment: You create too much instances I guess.

Comment: If I know it correctly, you get the error with the line numbers in the Flutter Console. Add the error details, and we will be able to clear it out.

Comment: @Alok could check this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64834014/flutter-sqlite-transaction-usage-error-warning-database-has-been-locked-for